# How to convert data from monthly to annual in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to convert monthly observations into annual -- year-country instead of month-country.

This is how the data looks:

```
year    month   countrycode troop
1990    1            USA    6
1990    2            USA    4
1990    3            CANADA 3
1990    4            CANADA 6
1991    1            USA    5
1991    2            USA    6
1991    3            CANADA 3
1991    4            CANADA 6
```

I would like to convert this into:

```
year    countrycode troop
1990         USA    10
1990         CANADA 9
1991         USA    11
1991         CANADA 9
```

I have no clue how to start so I'm grateful for all suggestions!

Comment: You need a group by sum `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(year, countrycode) %>% summarise(troop = sum(troop))`

Comment: Thanks! This worker great! May also ask how to group by sum if I want to do it for more than one variable? I tried: `df1 %>% group_by(year, countrycode) %>% summarise(troop = sum(troop), police=sum(police))` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use aggregate:

```
df_annual <- aggregate(troop ~ year + countrycode, df_monthly, sum)
```